# UTM parameters with Google Analytics

Tags: analytics, utm

i have got a problem, my website does not recognize character ?. so i can not use URL builder. As a parameter recognizes # but i don not think that this works with Google Ananlytics. Any ideas please???

Comment: I just tried it myself, the google utm url generator is automatically urlencoding all parameters, including `?`. The question is very unclear, please provide more details, exact error messages, snippets of logfiles, screenshots, ...

Comment: My URL does not contain a hashtag but if i put at the end of my URL /? OR ? and after this i set the parameters then it does not reload the same page but the browser shows a message server error. So my question is that my website for a reaason that i do not know does not accept /? 9or ? to pass the parameters so how can i implement utm parameter with url builder?